# Python Multiprocessing - Processes slowing each other process down

Tags: pyqt, multiprocessing

I have a PyQt app I am running that contains 4 separate multi-processes (not pool). I  have an video capture from a camera, a state machine, UI event handler, and machine learning inferencing.

I am working on reducing my ML inferencing as much as possible, so speed is my goal. I notice that when I pause my display for captured images, this will significantly speed up  my ML inferencing.

Displaying captured images is a process that happens between my video capture process and UI event handler process. Why is it that when I stop the images going from the video capture to the UI, does my ML inferencing speed up if they are all separate processes. Is there some overhead when spawning processes in the same app?

Here is the code that slows everything down significantly.

```
@pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
def update_image(self, cv_img):
    def convert_cv_qt(cv_img):
        """Convert from an opencv image to QPixmap"""
        h, w = cv_img.shape
        convert_to_Qt_format = QtGui.QImage(cv_img, w, h, w, QtGui.QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
        p = convert_to_Qt_format.scaled(self.vw.disply_width, self.vw.display_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        return QPixmap.fromImage(p)

    """Updates the image_label with a new opencv image"""
    qt_img = convert_cv_qt(cv_img)
    self.vw.image_label.setPixmap(qt_img)
```

The biggest time waster in this is below, which scales a 720x200 image to a 4k monitor, around 3000x1000

```
p = convert_to_Qt_format.scaled(self.vw.disply_width, self.vw.display_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

Comment: How is that function called? Please provide a [mre] or at least the portions related to it. Besides, it makes really little sense to use a local function that is being called just once.

Comment: The Video Capture process queues an image, in which the UI handler will then call this function with that image.

Comment: Still, we need a more comprehensive code to start with. Also note that, as far as I remember, a mp queue uses pickling, which may be quite intensive.